# SQL Order by Timestamp and Assign Numeric Value

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have a list of cust_id and timestamps for an activity.  I would like to add a column called "activity_order" which would give an order to each cust_id, which "1" being assigned to the max timestamp

```
 cust_id | time_stamp
 ________  __________
 a1        2015-01-31 10:48:43
 a1        2015-01-31 12:48:46
 a1        2015-01-31 17:50:40
 b1        2015-01-25 10:39:01
 b1        2015-01-31 12:53:34
```

This is what I want my desired result to look like:

```
 cust_id | time_stamp            | activity_order
 ________  ___________________    _________________
 a1        2015-01-31 10:48:43     3    
 a1        2015-01-31 12:48:46     2
 a1        2015-01-31 17:50:40     1
 b1        2015-01-25 10:39:01     2
 b1        2015-01-31 12:53:34     1
```

Here is my attempt, but the problem is this CASE statement is only so big, and I'm thinking I'll need a loop or something similar just in case a cust_id has greater than > 2 activities.

```
SELECT a.cust_id
,a.time_stamp
,CASE WHEN a.time_stamp = b.max_ts THEN 1 ELSE 2 END as activity_order
FROM ACTIVITY a
JOIN (SELECT
cust_id
,MAX(time_stamp) as max_ts
FROM activity_order) b
ON a.cust_id = b.cust_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT cust_id
, time_stamp
, RANK () OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) as activity_order
FROM activity
ORDER BY cust_id ASC, activity_order DESC
```

working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6d85/3

for more info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try assuming MS SQL

```
Update B
Set Activity_Order = RN
From
(select CustID, [Time_stamp], Row_Number() Over(Partition By CustID Order By [Time_stamp] desc) as RN
From Activity) A
inner join Activity B on A.CustID = B.CustID and A.[Time_stamp] = B.[Timestamp]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would us Row_Number with a partition by.
Note: You use 3 cust_ID : a1, b1, b2. But your example orders the b1 under b2. 
Is this an error in your example?

This is my try:

```
SELECT 
cust_id, time_stamp, 
activity_order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY cust_id     ASC, time_stamp DESC) 
FROM ACTIVITY
```